# Mysql Query for getting top 5 subcategory from each category

Tags: mysql

I need a single query; criteria is:

I want to select only latest 5 subcategory from each category;

current query is:

```
SELECT a.id,a.catagory_name,b.id as sucid,b.subcatagory_name
FROM category a
LEFT JOIN subcategory b ON a.id = b.catagory_id
WHERE a.active='y' AND b.active='y'
ORDER BY a.priority,b.subcatagory_name
```

Comment: Add a `LIMIT 5`?  Is that all you need? If you need more, please provide more information in your question.

Comment: Check this : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
SELECT a.id,a.catagory_name,b.id as sucid,b.subcatagory_name
FROM category a
LEFT JOIN subcategory b ON a.id = b.catagory_id
WHERE a.active='y' AND b.active='y'
ORDER BY a.priority,b.category_id DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

This may work for you.

Comment: Why the 0 in your limit? That's the default behavior.

Comment: Also the limit is applied on the whole result. This is not what was required.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

```
SELECT a.id,a.catagory_name,B.id as sucid,B.subcatagory_name
FROM category a 
(SELECT id,subcatagory_name FROM subcategory WHERE catagory_id = a.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS B
ON a.id = B.catagory_id
ORDER BY a.priority,B.category_id;
```